# Arduino - Linux - URG Library

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile, arduino, lidar

I have a couple questions regarding Arduino (Mega), Linux and how to load URG library.

So I am using Ubuntu Linux, version 13.04 (I believe), for a project and I downloaded the Arduino Software for Linux. I added the Sabertooth library for Linux into the Arduino Software, and also download and updated the Linux packages that contains the URG libraries. I also downloaded the Zip file of the "urg-library-1.1.9" and I added to the Arduino Software as well.

However this is where my actual question is. The errors I am seeing on the code is regardless to the libraries. The Arduino Software is not finding the file or directory to import the code from. For example: I have a #include "urg_sensor.h" and #include "urg_utils.h" and they as some others are not being found.

After spending the day reading and searching about the Makefile and on Readme.txt of the library, I found some useful information.
On the Readme.txt I found that I have to compile and run in Linux as the "decompress, ./configure and make."
The Makefile file says that I have to process this file with Automake to produce another file called Makfile.in.

I downloaded the "application/package" Automake in Linux and open several documents that help to understand/learn how to use it. After following the steps, I was able to install the urg_library, but I am still not able to run the Makefile file. I also found another information here on Stackoverflow about how to open and use "automake," and in one of the answers I figure that I could use "autoreconfig -i" to run. I tried both, but in both cases I receive this error on my screen monitor: 
autoreconf: 'configure.ac' or 'configure.in' is required
automake: error: 'configure.ac' is required

I do not have any of those files and I tried, unsuccessfully, a way to create or to find them.

My question is: how do I really run the Makefile file (with or without automake or autoreconf) and how do I makesure that the Arduino Software reads all the urg library.

My goal is: Connect the URG LX04 Laser Sensor to the Arduino to read date (distance, measurements, etc). I am using Ubuntu Linux version 13.04 (I belive) and I am stuck in the process of finding or making the Arduino read the "URG Linux library" without giving me errors.

Thank you very much for your attention and looking forward to get any response.

Answer (score 0):

The library you're trying to use here is written to allow access to the laser sensor *from a desktop computer*, and the directions you're trying to follow are for installing it on your computer.

The library will not work on an embedded device, like an Arduino, without some significant changes. (Discovering what the necessary changes will be is a sizable project on its own; I cannot give you step-by-step instructions here.)